# Will this isolating valve allow me to change a radiator valve without draining down?

Tags: radiator

One of the valves on my radiator (circled in red) has seized and my attempts to open it have snapped off the flat part of the head, so it now needs replacing.

My plan is to turn the isolating valve next to it to the vertical position and the other radiator valve (pictured for completeness) to zero.

Will this allow me drain just the radiator so I can change the valve circled in red?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Identifying info for the radiator itself (make/model) if known, as well as for the "other valve" (thermostat?) may not be _necessary_, but certainly won't hurt. Just [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work.

Just take care draining the rad, as the "water" can come out black and it stains anything :)

Comment: There need to be 2 isolating valves, or for the TRV to be set past the 0.

Comment: @IamOnStage I read the OP’s post where they clearly said that the thermostatic valve would also be used - did you miss that?

Comment: I did read it. When the valve is on zero, it will still let some water drip through. It needs to be passed this on * , as my answer says.  I am only trying to help and provide a detailed answer. Please don't downvote my answer, just trying to give back to a community.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of.

The valve on the 1st picture only cuts off 1 of the pipes to the radiator. There is still pressure and water on the other pipe that feeds the radiator (2nd pipe with the large white thermostat valve). If you only shut 1 off, then if you unscrew the radiator, water will still be coming in on the other pipe.

To be able to shut the water off to this radiator, you need these isolating valves on **both** the pipes going to the radiator.

If there is only 1 isolating value, make sure the other valve is fully turned off past the '0' and to the '*' .

Ideally, you need a pair of adjustable spanner and a pair of grips. Hold the valve body still with the grips and use the adjustable to unscrew. Holding it steady is important as if you yank it too hard and it moves too much, it may displace somewhere else and create another leak.

Have a container ready underneath to catch the water and you may need to fill this, close value, empty tub, then reopen a few times until the radiator is completely empty. The water can also be quite black, so also have an old towel to hand.

These valves are not meant to have the plastic cover turn the valve. These need to be done with an adjustable spanner. Please try this first as it may be OK.

If you need to change the whole valve body, keep the nut and olive on the pipe from the old, as removing an olive can be tricky and not necessary, as long as the new and old fittings are the same screw size. It is also a good idea to put a few turns of PTFE on an olive as this very much reduces the chances of leaks. Also, make sure you use 7-9 turns of PTFE tape on the new thread going into the radiator.

**If Leaking:**
If the valve is leaking on the threaded side (right side to the rad), as opposed to the underside compression fitting (to the pipe). I would first suggest you do not fit a new valve, as the compression is fine. But unscrew the right thread, clean and remove any PTFE tape. And then wrap around some more PTFE on it. At least 7-9 turns, it is surprising how much can go in. Then re-screw tightly and fill and check for leaks.

If the compression is leaking, I would still avoid changing, as removing the olive (round copper ring) can be difficult. I would keep the olive in place on the pipe and wrap a few turns of PTFE on the olive and then retighten. Removing an olive which has been fixed to a pipe can be difficult for a novice.

Comment: The OP did state they are using the thermostatic valve as the « other » valve to do the isolation.